# Solutions of $x^2-6x+\lfloor x \rfloor+7=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> What are the roots of $x^2-6x+\lfloor x \rfloor+7=0$, where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the greatest integer function?

Is there some way to solve the equation without graphing?

Comment: A possible strategy is to solve $x^2-6x+n+7=0$ for all integers $n$, and find out when a solution $x_0$ (this will be a function of $n$, something square-root-ish) satisfies $n\leqslant x_0<n+1$. The problem reduces to $2$ polynomial inequalities of degree $2$ in the variable $n$. There will be some casework, though.

Comment: Would inspection be acceptable ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici yes.

Comment: @barto $x_0$ would be a function of $n$ and $n$ itself is a function of $x$, so $x_0$ is a function of $x$...Would that give us the answer?

Comment: Is $[x]$ floor or ceiling ??

Comment: @YvesDaoust floor

Comment: Can I recommend you $\lfloor x\rfloor$ (`\lfloor x \rfloor`) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$x-1 < [x] \le x$, so $x^2-5x+6<0$ while $x^2-5x+7\ge 0$, which furthur reduces to $2<x<3$. We know $[x]=2$, so $x^2-6x+9=0$ and $x=3$. But this contradicts $x<3$ and hence no solution.

Comment: @shauryagupta, no, there is no solution, as I mentioned at the end.

Answer (score 9):

Given that $[x]=x+\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon$ in range $[0\ 1[$, you should study the parametric equation
$$x^2-5x+\epsilon+7=0.$$

Its discriminant is $25-4\epsilon-28$, always negative for the allowed $\epsilon$.

Comment: Yep, just two complex.

Answer (score 1):

The equation is equivalent to

$x=3\pm\sqrt{2-[x]}$

Suppose   $a\leq x<a+1$,  $a\in Z$

Then  $[x]=a$  and

$x=3-\sqrt{2-a}\geq\\\geq 3-(2-a)=a+1$

or

$x=3+\sqrt{2-a}\geq a+1$

This is a contradiction and, hence there are no real solutions.